# Connect DataBricks to Azure Storage Account with Networking Firewall using Service Principle

Tags: azure-storage, azure-databricks, firewall, azure-service-principal

I want my DataBricks to connect to my Azure Storage Account (blob). I am using a service principle for this connection.

The problem is that once I enable a networking firewall on my storage account, databricks tells me it is unauthorised to access the storage using the service principle, even though I have turned on the option “Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access the storage account”.

Does someone know how I can fix this? I don’t see whitelisting all IP addresses of Azure as an option.

Comment: You need to create a subnet with an ip range for your databricks VMs to use. You then whitelist that ip range

Answer (score 0):

If you enable a firewall rule on a storage account, this configuration only works with Azure Databricks if you [deploy Azure Databricks in your own virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/network/classic/vnet-injec), as shown below:

[image]

Add the VNet with the subnet where Databricks is deployed to the networking of the storage account as follows: Select "Add existing virtual network," choose the VNet and subnet, and click on "Enable." After enabling the subnet, click on "Add" and save the network settings as shown below:

[image]

Then, you can access the storage account successfully without any authorization issues.

[image]

This does not work with workspaces deployed without the VNet-injection feature. On the storage account, you have to enable access from the public Databricks subnet.