# azure, databricks, spark - can't connect with SAS token

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I am trying to get access to my azure storage container json file to read json files (data).
I have config my spark like this:

```
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.auth.type.{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.dfs.core.windows.net", "SAS")
        spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider")
        spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.dfs.core.windows.net", SAS_TOKEN)
        logging.info('spark was configured')
```

When I try to connect I get the error: `"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."` (403).

```
data = get_data_from_file(BLOB_PATH)
```

/* The SAS token is correct, the file path is correct.

** Firewall is enabled in the networking setting in the container (Disabling it doesn't help).

*** If I try to read from a different storage it works, but why, I didn't do something in the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature." (403)

There are multiple reasons for this issue:

- If you are using blob storage, then you have to use `wasbs` and not `abfss`. I have tried using below code with my `SAS` token and got the same error with my blob storage.

> ** Firewall is enabled in the networking setting in the container (Disabling it doesn't help).**

To access files from azure blob storage where the firewall settings are  `only from selected networks`,

- You need to configure  `VNet`  for the Databricks workspace.
- Now add the same virtual network to your storage account as well.
- I have also selected  `service endpoints`  and  `subnet delegation`  as following:
- Now run the code to get the data from ADLS File.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77703281) SO answer for reference